# $L^p$-bounding inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Do we have that$$\|Du\|_{L^{2p}} \le C\|u\|_{L^\infty}^{1\over2} \|D^2u\|_{L^p}^{1\over2}$$for $1 \le p < \infty$ and all $u \in C_c^\infty(U)$? Here, $U$ denotes an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am wondering if there is a way to see this that does not just involve invoking something such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality), i.e. a direct proof would be nice.

Comment: What is $U$? Open, bounded?

Comment: Crossposted on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233106/lp-bounding-inequality).